# What does the map and flat map operations mean for a ReaderMonad

Tags: scala, reader-monad

I am a scala newbie. I come from a background of Java. I have been reading up on monads and have formed a general idea about it. While i can appreciate the `map` and `flatMap` operations on types such as `List` i cannot wrap my head around what they mean when it comes to `reader monad`s. 
Could someone please put up some simple examples of it.

I understand we need ReaderMonads to facilitate unary function composition so that we can use fancy syntax like for - comprehensions. I also understand that we need the monad gods satisfied in order for that to happen.
All i want to understand is "What does map and flatmap" mean for functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reader monad, often written `Reader[A, B]`, is just the function type `A => B`. An encoding of monads in Scala looks like:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): M[A]
  def flatMap[A, B](ma: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

where `map` can be implemented in terms of `pure` and `flatMap` like so:

```
def map[A, B](ma: M[A])(f: A => B): M[B] = flatMap(ma)(a => pure(f(a)))
```

So first thing we need to do is to make our binary type constructor `Reader` fit into the unary type constructor that `Monad` expects. This is done by fixing the first (input) type parameter and leaving the second (output) type parameter free.

```
implicit def readerMonad[X]: Monad[X => ?] = ???
```

(The use of `?` here is via the wonderful [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) compiler plugin).

Starting with `pure`, we substitue occurences of `M[_]` with `X => _`.

```
def pure[A](a: A): X => A
```

Given some value of type `A`, we must return a function that given a value of type `X`, returns a value of type `A`. The only thing this can possibly be is the constant function.

```
def pure[A](a: A): X => A = _ => a
```

Now substituting `flatMap`..

```
def flatMap[A, B](ma: X => A)(f: A => (X => B)): X => B = (x: X) => ???
```

This is a bit tricky, but we can use types to guide us to the implementation! We have:

```
ma: X => A
f: A => (X => B)
x: X
```

And we want to get a `B`. The only way we know how to do that is via `f`, which wants an `A` and an `X`. We have exactly one `X` from `x`, but we need an `A`. We see we can only get an `A` from `ma`, which wants an `X`, which again only `x` provides us. Therefore we have..

```
def flatMap[A, B](ma: X => A)(f: A => (X => B)): X => B =
  (x: X) => {
    val a = ma(x)
    val b = f(a)(x)
    b
  }
```

Read aloud, `flatMap` on `Reader` says to read some value `A` out of the "environment" (or "config") `X`. Then, branching on `A`, read another value `B` from the environment.

We can go ahead and implement `map` manually as well:

```
def map[A, B](ma: X => A)(f: A => B): X => B = ???
```

Looking at the arguments `X => A` and `A => B`, with the expected output `X => B`, this looks exactly like function composition, which indeed it is.

Example usage using [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) with imports:

```
import cats.data.Reader
```

Let's say we have some `Config` type:

```
case class Config(inDev: Boolean, devValue: Int, liveValue: Int)
```

which tells us whether or not we're in a "dev" environment and gives us values for something for "dev" and for "live." We can start by writing a simple `Reader[Config, Boolean]` which read out the `inDev` flag for us.

```
val inDev: Reader[Config, Boolean] = Reader((c: Config) => c.inDev)
```

And we can write a plain function that, given some boolean, will read the appropriate value.

```
def branch(flag: Boolean): Reader[Config, Int] =
  if (flag) Reader((c: Config) => c.devValue)
  else      Reader((c: Config) => c.liveValue)
```

Now we can compose the two:

```
val getValue: Reader[Config, Int] =
  for {
    flag <- inDev
    value <- branch(flag)
  } yield value
```

And now we can get our `Int` by passing in various `Config` values:

```
getValue.run(Config(true, 1, 2)) // 1
getValue.run(Config(false, 1, 2)) // 2
```

This in general can be used as a nice way to achieve dependency injection, using just functions!

Comment: Thx for the answer. Very deep. I need to read this multiple times and see if i understand completely. Can you also provide me some simple examples of usage ?